# Is the concept of Sattvik, Rajasik, Tamasik food found in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, gita

> **Sattvik**
>
> [BG 17.8](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/17/verse/8): *Persons in the mode of goodness prefer foods that promote the life span, and increase virtue, strength, health, happiness, and satisfaction. Such foods are juicy, succulent, nourishing, and naturally tasteful*.

> **Rajasik**
>
> [BG 17.9](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/17/verse/9): *Foods that are too bitter, too sour, salty, very hot, pungent, dry, and chiliful, are dear to persons in the mode of passion. Such foods produce pain, grief, and disease*.

> **Tamasik**
>
> [BG 17.10](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/17/verse/10): *Foods that are overcooked, stale, putrid, polluted, and impure are dear to persons in the mode of ignorance*.

**My QUESTION : Is the concept of ***Satvik rajasik tamasik foods*** found in the Vedas or upanishads ?**

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. What about food. Can you give reference to the food

Comment: @Mr.Sigma I have made some changes. now it is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Yes, now it can be opened. Nice :)

Comment: @Vivikta thank you :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no concept of such foods in the Vedas. The reason is that the very idea of Sattva, Rajasa and Tamasa Gunas is not there in the vedas. These are concepts of Samkhya Darsana.

> The concept of prakriti is used in Sankhya philosophy to explain the
> evolution of the universe. Prakriti is defined as the ultimate
> unconscious primal matter (both gross and subtle) or the ultimate
> cosmic energy, believed to be the material cause of the universe.
>
> ...............
>
> Prakriti has three inherent properties or attributes, known as the
> three gunas: sattva, rajas, and tamas. In Sanskrit guna means quality.
> Sattva represents the quality of goodness, balance and harmony, Rajas
> represents passion, restlessness and activity. Tamas represents
> dullness, inertia and laziness.

**The Hindu Mind by Bansi Pandit**

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but we know that gita is the summery of vedas and upanishades, so how can it contain concepts that are not found in the Vedas?

Comment: Lord Krishna is teaching Arjuna and us. So he is using concepts that were present in his time to aid his teaching. There is no need for all these concepts to be in the Vedas.