# What is the Vedic view of the sattvik food?

Tags: vedas, adi-shankaracharya, vivekananda, plants, sattvik

***Vivekananda*** claimed that food (such as the flesh of animals) obtained ' by taking the life of another ' is ***impure*** ' by its very nature '([Swami Vivekananda’s Quotes On Food](https://vivekavani.com/swami-vivekananda-quotes-food)). In the light of this view, all food stuff obtained from ***plants & trees*** is also impure as plants & trees also have ***life***. Almost all fruits and food grain as well as other plant seeds contain ***live embryos*** as the fertilized poultry eggs do. Vivekananda seems to be unaware of this fact. Nevertheless, ***Adi Shankara*** was aware that ' objects (like the tree) are endowed with sentience '. This made me curious about the Vedic view of the ***sattvik*** food.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the concept of Sattvik, Rajasik, Tamasik food found in the Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45477/is-the-concept-of-sattvik-rajasik-tamasik-food-found-in-the-vedas)

Comment: Regarding your doubt with "eating-living plants is a Sin?": Answer is Very Much YES. [Read This QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/97/why-can-we-eat-living-plants-but-not-living-animals). But, since every action is bound to generate a Karma, and mostly if looked at from scriptural injunction, most actions generate a "negative-one" thus, a Sin. One cannot follow everything in the scriptures to the "T" and still be a human (at least not in this age). There's a popular saying: *"A couple who followed each & every injunction in the scriptures, finally gives birth to a Dog"*

Comment: But what's your rationale behind regarding it as 'a Sin'?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/97/why-can-we-eat-living-plants-but-not-living-animals  READ the QnAs properly.

Comment: But then Swamiji himself ate fish and meat,right?